# Intercepting Thick client applications over HTTPS

Tags: tls

is there a way to intercept and do pentest on thick client applications which are running over HTTPS?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: See Stephane's answer. That will work. If you don't have a favorite proxy, Google 'fiddler3'. It's fairly easy to configure on Windows

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application but usually, that is no problem if you have root on the system

Check what Host name the application uses, create a cert for that name, add it to the machine or application trusted root store and redirect Host name to a proxy server you control.

After that, either configure the proxy to dump the clear text content of the communication somewhere or sniff the top connection between the proxy and client and use the fake certificate private key to decrypt it